# single quote added in the space of a variable value in unix script

Tags: unix

I have a date variable in a script and I have a string of parameter list comes from another file. Have tried to do eval to evaluate the date value in the parameter string. The date value would be like "2017-03-08 13:23:00". When the value gets evaluated in the parameter string, the space between the date and time part is enclosed with single quote, which consider the whole parameter string as invalid argument while passing to execute a command. Below are the examples.

Parameter string in the file:

```
-param Start_date=${St_date} -param End_date=${End_date} -param test='tst'\''
```

Lines in the script:

```
test1='tst'
St_date='2017-03-08 13:23:00'
End_date='2017-03-09 13:22:00'

#parameter string will be grep and assigned to variable param_list
#eval cmd below

paramlist=$(eval echo $(echo $param_list))

# when use paramlist to call a job, it displays below 

-param Start_date='\''2017-03-08' '13:23:00'\'' -param End_date='\''2017-03-    09' '13:22:00'\''  -param test='\''tst'\''
```

How to remove the single quote between date and time part. Please suggest.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It is not really clear. You want to avoid a single quote _you just put in_? Perhaps use double quotes `-param Start_date="$St_date"` or `-param Start_date="'$St_date'"` (quote, single quote, $St_date, single quote, quote)?

Comment: Use below to remove single quote from date - 
`echo $End_date|awk -F\' '{print $0}'`
and put it in another variable.